# The behavior of a C compiler with old-styled functions without prototypes

Tags: c, function, declaration, implicit, function-prototypes

When my program consists of two files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
     printf("%lf\n",f());   
     return 0;
 }
```

func.c

```
double f(int a) {
 return 1;
}
```

compiler do not show any errors.

When my program consists of only one file:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
     printf("%lf\n",f());   
     return 0;
 }

double f(int a) {
 return 1;
}
```

Visual C++ 2008 compiler show the following error:

```
Error 2 error C2371: 'f' : redefinition; different basic types d:\temp\projects\function1\function1\1.c 8 function1
```

Can anybody explain this strange behavior?

Comment: as I understand:

in the first case the linker is responsible for binding the call of the function with its definition;

in the second case the compiler is responsible for binding the call of the function with its definition.

Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the programs are wrong.

Without a prototype in scope, a compiler assumes that a function returns `int` and takes an unspecified number of parameters.

Let's change your files a bit:

```
$ cat func.c
double f(int a) {
    return 1.0;
}
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
    double d = f();
    printf("%lf\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, gcc warns me (Visual C++ should too, in conformant mode).  But let's ignore the warning.

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -W -Wall func.c main.c -o test
func.c:1: warning: unused parameter 'a'
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'f'
$ ./test
0.000000
```

It did not print 1, but printed 0.  This is because the compiler assumed that `f()` returned an `int`, and the assignment `d = f();` converted that "`int`" to a `double`.  The compiler still compiled the code because it couldn't tell that `f()` wasn't defined the way it was (implicitly) declared.  But compiling the above program isn't required by the standard, so the compiler could have rejected it (try with `gcc -Werror` for example!)

If we have everything in one file:

```
$ cat func.c >>main.c
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -W -Wall func.c main.c -o test
main.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'f'
main.c: At top level:
main.c:9: error: conflicting types for 'f'
main.c:4: error: previous implicit declaration of 'f' was here
main.c:9: warning: unused parameter 'a'
```

Now the compiler sees the conflict, and gives you an error message.  But, a compiler is not required to reject the above program, it may or may not.

Most compilers don't reject the first program because they don't know if you have a correct definition of the function `f()` in another translation unit or not.  They reject the second program because they *know* that you don't.

Answer (score 6):

C will assume a function has the prototype int func(); unless you have told it otherwise.(Note that in C int func(); and int func(void); are different things)

In your second case, you do a call to `f()` for which the compiler hasn't seen any prototype, so it assumes it is `int f();` . Later on it sees your definition for `f()` which has a different prototype - and issues an error.

This doesn't happen in the 1. case, as they're in different compilation units.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example never uses `func.c` so I'm not sure exactly what the compiler is doing about `f()` because it has no definition.

In the second example, I don't know why you can't have two functions with different signatures, but you aren't calling the function you've defined. You call `f()` with no arguments, but the `f` you define takes an int which makes it a different function.